# How to initialize array in java when the class constructor has parameters?

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

I have this class constructor:

```
public Category(int max){
...
}
```

The thing is, I want to make an array of this class, how do I initialize it?

```
private Category categories = new Category(max)[4];
```

Does not work.

***UPDATE***

Do I need to do something like this?

```
private Category[] categories = new Category[4];
```

And then initialize each object?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you are making an array , you are creating an array of Category. That s an instance of array.

When you are populating the array with Category objects, at that point you use the Category with Const.

```
Category [] categories = new Category[4];
categories[0] = new Category(10);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also do that in-line - make both the array and populate it with values initiated with their constructors at once. Suppose you have a class called Field that has a constructor taking two parameters and you want to construct an array of these ...

```
Field[] fields = new Field[]{
    new Field(1, "Record_Type"),
    new Field(3, "Record_SubType"),
    new Field(6, "Row_Number"),
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 7):

```
private Category[] categories = new Category[4];
```

Will be instantiated with 4 null categories, you have to fill the content yourself later.
Or you can try:

```
private Category[] categories = {new Category(max), new Category(max), new Category(max), new Category(max)};
```

Answer (score 3):

Initialize it as an array first

```
Category[] categories = new Categories[4];
categories[0] = new Category(max);
```

Then initialize each individual element.